# Access: Navigate to Existing Record to Avoid Duplicate - Error 2169

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling

I have a pop-up form where records are uniquely identified by a combination of fields. When a user is about to create a duplicate record, I want to prompt them to either navigate to the existing record or choose a different combination of fields. My two attempts are shown below, but both result in Error 2169.

Attempt 1:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim answer As String, strConditions As String
    Dim rsc As Recordset
    Dim db As DAO.Database

    strConditions = "Fund='" & Fund.Value & "' AND Department='" & _
    Department.Value & "' AND Object='" & Object.Value & "' AND Subcode='" & Subcode.Value & _
    "' AND TrackingCode='" & TrackingCode.Value & "' AND Reserve='" & Reserve.Value & _
    "' AND FYEnd=" & FYEnd.Value & " AND MonthlySpreadID<>" & MonthlySpreadID.Value

    If DCount("*", "[Monthly Spread]", strConditions) = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    answer = MsgBox("An entry with this coding already exist." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "Would you like to be navigated to the existing record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Duplicate Record.")

    If answer = vbYes Then
        Me.Undo
        Cancel = True
        Me.Filter = ""
        Set rsc = Me.RecordsetClone
        rsc.FindFirst strConditions
        Me.Bookmark = rsc.Bookmark
        Set rsc = Nothing
    Else
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Duplicates are not allowed. Please enter a different combination of dimensions.", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

Attempt #2

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    Dim answer As String, strConditions As String
    Dim rsc As Recordset

    Select Case DataErr

    Case 3022
        Response = acDataErrContinue 'prevent Access from displaying its own error message

        strConditions = "Fund='" & Fund.Value & "' AND Department='" & _
        Department.Value & "' AND Object='" & Object.Value & "' AND Subcode='" & Subcode.Value & _
        "' AND TrackingCode='" & TrackingCode.Value & "' AND Reserve='" & Reserve.Value & _
        "' AND FYEnd=" & FYEnd.Value

        answer = MsgBox("An entry with this coding already exist." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "Would you like to be navigated to the existing record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Duplicate Record.")

        If answer = vbYes Then
            Me.Undo
            Me.Filter = ""
            Set rsc = Me.RecordsetClone
            rsc.FindFirst strConditions
            Me.Bookmark = rsc.Bookmark
            Set rsc = Nothing
        Else
            Me.Undo
            Me.Refresh
            MsgBox "Duplicates are not allowed. Please enter a different combination of dimensions.", vbInformation
        End If

    Case 2169
        Response = acDataErrContinue
        'How do I choose No from error message?
    Case Else
        Response = acDataErrDisplay 'cause Access to display its own error message
    End Select
End Sub
```

The problem with both attempts is that after I navigate to the duplicate record, I get error 2169: [image]

I need to either avoid this error or select "No" using VBA. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you step debugged? I cannot replicate issue.

Comment: Yes. In the first attempt the error happens after the sub ends. In the second attempt I'm able to trap the error, but if I use Response=acDataErrContinue, it chooses Yes from the error window and closes the form. I think in both cases I'm preventing the update from happening, but I need to somehow prevent the form from closing.

Comment: Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.